# Why the other list also changes if I have changed the data of one list?

Tags: c#, list

I have one class

```
class MatchAddress
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Taluka { get; set; }
    public string District { get; set; }
    public string Pincode { get; set; }
    public float Rank { get; set; }
}
```

I have create new list using this class as mentioned below

```
var dst = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                      .Select(s => new MatchAddress 
                       { 
                           Name = s.Field<String>("officename").Trim().ToLower(), 
                           Pincode = Convert.ToString(s.Field<double>("pincode")).Trim(), 
                           Taluka = s.Field<String>("Taluk").Trim(),
                           District = s.Field<String>("Districtname").Trim(), 
                           Rank = 0f 
                       })
                      .ToList();
```

I have also initialize new list  `List<MatchAddress> lm;`

Now I'm assign `dst` list to `lm` like below

```
lm = dst ;


foreach (MatchAddress ma in lm)
{                       
    if (ma.Name == "xyz")
    {                              
        ma.Pincode = null;
    }
}
```

after this sure the Property `Pincode`  for the list `lm` set to `null` where name = "XYZ".

and for that reason list `lm` are update  and set pincode field null .

**but my question are that why that list lm also update the result  of list dst.**

and `lm` list also set pincode null in the list `dst`.

and we make the clone of the `dst` list into `lm` so why list `lm` change the also list dst ??

I know to reason behind this not the answer why this happen if you know then please let me now.

I don't want to the answer of this question

Comment: You are not making a clone of `dst`, you assign the `dst` List to the `lm` List which is assigned by reference, that is why both lists are changing.

Answer (score 1):

List is a reference type data. but you can make clone if you want. here is the simple extension method for that

```
static class Extensions
    {
        public static IList<T> Clone<T>(this IList<T> listToClone) where T: ICloneable
        {
            return listToClone.Select(item => (T)item.Clone()).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because List is a reference type data. Both lm and dst are pointing to the same data.  If you want both lists to be **independent**, you can do it as:

```
List<MatchAddress> lm = dst.ConvertAll(address => new MatchAddress(Name = address.Name, Pincode = address.Pincode, Taluka= address.Taluka, District = address.District, Rank = address.Rank));
```

Comment: This question has already been asked thousand of times here on SO, no need to answer it again and agin

Comment: @ADMIN does it work?